# How to put all of the javascript loaded through ajax or jquery.load in a non-global child scope

Tags: javascript, ajax, iframe, web, closures

I'm trying to get around iframe by using ajax/jquery.load() and inject a third party page on my site (CORS requirements are not a issues here as the third party sets the appropriate CORS response headers).

So my question is: Let's say that the main host site loads jquery 1.x and a bunch of other libs. And let's say that the third party page loads jquery 2.x and some other conflicting libraries with the main site.

How can I refactor my JS on the third party page so that it's not loadedin JS global scope but in a shielded child scope.

Can I wrap everything in function(){}?? Including the jquery libs etc? If so how do I access the methods/vars in this child scope on the third party page?

Let me know if I need to provide any more details...

Comment: If you do need to load them as separate libs, you will need to use (some part of) the global scope. Otherwise, bundle them into one script and wrap that in an IEFE - you're done.

Answer (score 0):

`iframes` by default load an entire `document` on their own, and are pretty much shielded to everything, you can allow modals/popup/etc with the sandbox attribute, if none specified it will just show content, and won't interact with the upper layer.

To access the function inside an `iframe`, you can:

`document.getElementById("resultFrame").contentWindow.Reset()`

This will run the `Reset()` Global Function inside the iframe with `resultFrame` ID.